# Pythonic way to map a list of objects to a list of a particular field

Tags: python-2.7

Given:

```
[{'a': '30152', 'b': 'test1', 'c': '10'}, {'a': '30153', 'b': 'test2', 'c': '6'}]
```

what would I do in Python in order to get the results

```
['test1', 'test2']
```

In Java 8 I would do the following:

```
list.stream().map(Row::getB).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `map(operator.itemgetter('b'), list)`? `[item['b'] for item in list]`? Although either way `list` is a bad name for your own list, as it shadows the built-in type.

Comment: Hi yes thanks for that. i only used the word 'list' for the the benefit of showing an example but thanks i wasnt aware of that. 

Is that one whole command by the way or 2 seperates?

Comment: Why not try it out and see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a maping function that you'll run on every element of your tuple/list of dictionaries
Then you can call function map with your created map function and your list of dictionaries.

```
def mapB(dict): return dict['b']
myDicts = {'a': '30152', 'b': 'test1', 'c': '10'}, {'a': '30153', 'b': 'test2', 'c': '6'}
list = map(mapB,myDicts)
```

If you want to create it more dynamicaly, then you can use some map function like this one.

```
myDicts = {'a': '30152', 'b': 'test1', 'c': '10'}, {'a': '30153', 'b': 'test2', 'c': '6'}
list = map(lambda x: x['b'], dict)
```

Comment: Note that your `mapB` is already provided by Python in the more general form `operator.itemgetter`.